# Laravel Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make an ajax request from my homepage in Laravel. But I am unable to figure out what resource to request for. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!!

My HTML:

```
<input name="login" id="login" type="button" value="Log In" class="flat-button" onclick="getLoginForm();" />
<input name="signup" id="signup" type="button" value="Sign Up" class="flat-button" onclick="getSignUpForm();" />
```

My JS:

```
function getLoginForm() {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("modal").style.visibility="visible";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/showLoginForm",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And My Laravel Route:

```
Route::get('/showLoginForm', 'PowerUserController@showLoginForm');
```

Comment: the requested ressource seems to be okay. Does the controller method exist and is it written correctly?

Comment: Yeah... My controller has the following method:

    public function showLoginForm() {
 return View::make('powerUser.showLoginForm');
    }

The problem is that my modal popup is not being filled with the show LoginForm view - its being filled by my showHomePage view :(

    public function showWelcome() {
        return View::make('powerUser.welcome');
    }

Comment: What do you get when you try to hit the route in the browser?

Comment: Whoops looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Then turn on debbung in your `app/config/app.php` and check **what is wrong**

Comment: Hey sorry about the delayed response. I think there was a typo somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. It's always a good idea to turn on debugging while you're in the development phase. Also when working with AJAX your Web Inspectors `network` tab is your best friend

Comment: Yeah, I mean I have it turned on now. I just figured it should be turned on by default, no? 

Anywhoo ... I'm loving Laravel.